# Remove unnecessary string from a list

Tags: typescript

I am going to loop through a list of urls and my question is that how can I only loop through links with 'http://' at the beginning? I wrote below code however it didn't give me what I need.

```
export class LoopThroughLinks {
  loopurl() {
    let newurls = [];
    for (let i in getonetags) {
        if (i.startsWith('http://')) {
            let newurl = ParseSingleHtml.getPageContent(i);
            newurls.push(newurl);
            console.log(newurls);
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and check string object with a regex.

e.g.:

```js
const urls = [
'http://google.com/',
'https://google.com/',
'www.google.com/',
'google.com/',
];

for (let url of urls.filter(o => /^http:\/\//.test(o))) {
console.log(url);
}
```